# Pivot a dataframe with duplicates in the column keeping all the records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are SO questions similar to this one however I can't find a way here.
My data frame is:
[image]

I just want to get the given dataframe in the form:

[image]

I did this:

```
new = pd.pivot_table(ratings,values='Book-Rating',index='User-ID',columns='ISBN')
```

The issue is that the duplicate ISBNs are apparently being dropped here. However I want all the data, not ISBN is showing more than 1 rating as duplicates have been dropped.

I also tried pivot but from an SO answer I found out pivot_table and using aggfunc will cater the duplicates. However I am not sure what value to pass in to aggfunc.

Also, the records in the data are more than 400k and I get 'index is out of bounds with axis of size' error as well.

Any guidance in the correct direction is appreciated, I can provide the dataframe as well if required. Let me know.

Comment: when you say that duplicate ISBNs are being dropped - are you saying that a single User-ID has rated the same ISBN multiple times?

Comment: Ok my bad I think I got confused. I will modify/delete. But is there a way to prevent the index out of bounds error? Thanks'

Comment: you've got too many columns, is that the issue? since you have a column for each unique ISBN?

Comment: Exactly. There are just too many columns. That's probably why the error comes up

Comment: ok, i'm not sure on that - I think you should either re-write this question to focus on that or (probably easier at this point) close this question and open a new one focused specifically on that issue of having too many columns. Looking at your title and how this question starts, your core issue is very buried in here at this point.